# Need some advice on displaying an image in a div

Tags: php, image, html, wysiwyg

I have a WYSIWYG editor, which is used to create articles. The articles are then inserted into a database. The article is then displayed on the main page. It consists of 2 major divs/parts. The top part is a div with fixed height and is used to display an image that is submitted by the WYSIWYG(that's the plan) for the specific article. So, user(with privilege) writes article, inserts/uploads an image(which is located on the server), article gets inserted into DB and the url of the image as well.

My question is how I should display it? Right now I'm thinking of pulling all the required fields from the database and placing the image url into the div and it will render as an image. This feels really clunky, so with my limited experience I wonder if there's a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: that's about it. if you want an image in an html page, you need a `<img>` tag, or maybe a `<canvas>`... unless, of course, you're trying to render ASCII art.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Pull the image URL from the database, then pop it into an img tag within the div, OR apply it as a background on the div itself.

For sizing the image to fit in the div, specify either the height or width of the image. The other will automatically size, keeping the proper aspect ratio. This can cause problems with it fitting in the div of a fixed height, so you will want to set the CSS overflow property on the div to hidden, so that images do not overflow outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

You mean storing the image path in a DB then echoing it in an  tag?

There's nothing wrong with that... better than storing the image in the DB if that's what you were wondering?